# How To Use Integer in Form Data Submit via Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, forms, resttemplate

I have an endpoint to which I need to submit a form.
The structure is:

```
employeeName : "Smith" -> String
employeeId : 1024 -> Integer
employeeDesignation : "Manager" -> String
```

I have the following method that uses restTemplate to submit form data:

```
private void submitDetails(Long employeeId, String employeeName, String employeeDesignation) {

    try {
        FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        logger.info("Submitting employee details for id "+employeeId);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
        formData.add("employeeName", employeeName);
        formData.add("employeeId", employeeId.toString());
        formData.add("employeeDesignation", employeeDesignation);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity(formData, headers);

        restTemplate.messageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        ResponseEntity<Map> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(
            "http://trainingempsite.azurewebsites.net/employee", request, Map.class);
        logger.info("Successfully submitted Employee Details");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while submitting Employee Details", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The postForEntity receives a 400 Bad Request.
However;
when I submit same details through Postman/ curl,
it gets submitted successfully when I use employeeId as number.

Reference curl example :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://trainingempsite.azurewebsites.net/employee \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data 'employeeName=Smith' \
  --data 'employeeId=4' \
  --data 'employeeDesignation=Manager'
```

Comment: @Tom Yes, Its 400 Bad Request, not 404. Editing my comment

Comment: Why not make a map of String, Objects and try submitting I’d as a number?

Comment: J Asgarov tried it , doesn't work. It gives error message `no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type java.util.Map`

Comment: Give some details about how you submit the form using Postman

Comment: @DwB have added example of curl request.